# aws codebuild COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

When I use aws, during the codebuild process, an error is reported. It may be a docker problem or other problems, I am not sure.
I used amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0 docker, based on which I added pnpm and nginx.
this is my code

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0

RUN yum update -y && yum install -y gcc-c++ make

RUN npm install -g pnpm@8.9.0

RUN yum clean all

WORKDIR /app
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
#      - echo Begin pull nginx:stable-alpine3.17-slim
#      - docker pull nginx:stable-alpine3.17-slim
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username ${AWS_USER_NAME} --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com.cn
      - REPOSITORY_URI=${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com.cn/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo ${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION} | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${ENV_LATEST}-${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo change to tencent npm
      - echo Install started
      - pnpm install
      - echo Build started
      - pnpm run build:${PROJECT_ENV}
      - echo Copy dist resource
      - cp -r dist docker/
      - echo Building the docker image...
      - docker build -t ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} ./docker/
      - docker tag ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${IMAGE_TAG}
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST}
      - docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${IMAGE_TAG}
cache:
  paths:
    - '/root/.npm/**/*'
```

When executing codebuild，throw error

```
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:48 Running command docker build -t ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} ./docker/
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:51 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} ./docker/ exit status 1
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:51 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:51 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} ./docker/. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:51 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:51 Running command echo Pushing the Docker image...
Pushing the Docker image...

[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:52 Running command docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST}
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:52 Command did not exit successfully docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST} exit status 1
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:52 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/10/17 02:42:52 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push ${REPOSITORY_URI}:${ENV_LATEST}. Reason: exit status 1
```

what should i do？ thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the `buildspec.yml`

```
  - /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
  - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
```